# Show WordPress gallery on home like a post with easy FancyBOX

Tags: wordpress, function, post, fancybox, gallery

I try to show an WordPress Gallery on home page, but with the same effect present in a post page. Basically is show the gallery post on homepage when you clicking a post-thumb. I explain the problem:

When I click on post_thumb, show in the home I like this show me, a Gallery attatch in this post. This my code:

```
                <ul id="rb-grid" class="list rb-grid">

            <?php $number = 0; query_posts('category_name=atracciones-home'); if(have_posts()): ?>
                <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                    <!-- <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="item fancybox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> -->
                    <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="item fancybox iframe" href="<?php get_attachment_link(); ?>">


                            <?php
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
                                    the_post_thumbnail('home-atracciones');
                                else
                            echo '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'img/default-thumbnail.png' . '" alt="" />';
                            ?>



                            <div class="over" id="gallery-atracciones">
                                <h2 class="page-title" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><span class="border"></span></h2>                     
                            </div>




                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-fancybox

Answer (score 0):

Need to check is_home() [For More Details about is_home() function Click Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

```
 <?php
    if ( is_home() ) {
        // This is the blog posts index

  <ul id="rb-grid" class="list rb-grid">

            <?php $number = 0; query_posts('category_name=atracciones-home'); if(have_posts()): ?>
                <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                    <!-- <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="item fancybox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> -->
                    <a data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="item fancybox iframe" href="<?php get_attachment_link(); ?>">


                            <?php
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
                                    the_post_thumbnail('home-atracciones');
                                else
                            echo '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'img/default-thumbnail.png' . '" alt="" />';
                            ?>



                            <div class="over" id="gallery-atracciones">
                                <h2 class="page-title" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><span class="border"></span></h2>                     
                            </div>

                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
    } else {
        // This is not the blog posts index
        get_sidebar();
    }
    ?>
```